# How to combine mean fare of both applicable time for the all distances for each fare_type?

Tags: python

[image]
i need help in combining the mean fare for each type of fare_type with distance still remaining the same

i tried using 3 for loop after cleaning but just cant get it.
[image]

```
mrt = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\fares-for-mrt-and-lrt-effective-from-26-december-2022.csv',na_values = 'na')
mrt
word = '-'
word2 = 'Up to '
word3 = 'Over'
for x in range(len(mrt)):
    mrt['distance'][x] = str(mrt['distance'][x]).replace('km','')
    if '-' in mrt['distance'][x]:
        mrt['distance'][x] = mrt['distance'][x].split(word,1)
        mrt['distance'][x] = float(mrt['distance'][x][1])
    elif 'Up to' in mrt['distance'][x]:
        mrt['distance'][x] = mrt['distance'][x].split(word2,1)
        mrt['distance'][x] = float(mrt['distance'][x][1])
    elif 'Over'in mrt['distance'][x]:
        mrt['distance'][x] = mrt['distance'][x].split(word3,1)
        mrt['distance'][x] = float(mrt['distance'][x][1]) + 0.1

# for type in np.unique(mrt):
avgMrtDist = float(round(avgDist['MRT'],1))
# cost = mrt[mrt['distance'] == (mrt['distance'][mrt['distance'] > avgMrtDist].min())]
# for title in np.unique(mrt['fare_type']):
#     for morn,aft in np.unique(mrt['applicable_time']):
            for x in range(len(mrt)):
                mrt['mean'] = 
        # if mrt[title][morn]


mrt[mrt['distance'] == 'Adult card fare'][mrt['applicable_time'] == 'All other timings']
```

source of csv: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/fare-structure-mrts-and-lrts

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the problem than "just can't get it"?

Comment: i am lost on how to match the fare_type and distance together with the timing/fare being the independent variable